# How can I make this code more Pythonic - specifically, merging something into a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that this code would look a lot better if I made it so that checking the current prices against the open prices were in a function so I wouldn't have to re-write it for every stock I want to check, but I'm not sure how to get started on doing that properly.  Do any of you have some tips to get me started?

```
from yahoo_finance import Share

apple = Share('AAPL')

appleopen = float(apple.get_open())
applecurrent = float(apple.get_price())

if appleopen > applecurrent:
    print(("Apple is down for the day. Current price is"), applecurrent)
else:
    print(("Apple is up for the day! Current price is "), applecurrent)

applechange = (applecurrent - appleopen)
if applechange > 0:
    print(('The price moved'),abs(applechange),("to the upside today."))
else:
    print(('The priced moved'),abs(applechange),("to the downside today."))
print('-----------------------')
nflx = Share('NFLX')

nflxopen = float(nflx.get_open())
nflxcurrent = float(nflx.get_price())

if nflxopen > nflxcurrent:
    print(("Netflix is down for the day. Current price is"), nflxcurrent)
else:
    print(("Netflix is up for the day! Current price is "), nflxcurrent)

nflxchange = (nflxcurrent - nflxopen)
if nflxchange > 0:
    print(('The price moved'),abs(nflxchange),("to the upside today."))
else:
    print(('The priced moved'),abs(nflxchange),("to the downside today."))
```

Comment: You should see that your code is essentially the same for both, apart from the `str` you pass to `Share`. You could simply wrap that bit in a function that takes the `str` as an argument. If you want the full names of the company printed, you'd have to deal with that separately, i.e. map them in a `dict` with the `str` as keys. Alternatively, you could just print the `str` you're passing

Comment: @hjpotter92 That is not a valid close reason.

Comment: @hjpotter92 not to be nitpicky, but "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking" would be better. Being on-topic elsewhere doesn't make a question off-topic here. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
Store = {
    'AAPL': 'Apple',
    'NFLX': 'Netflix'
}
for code in Store:
    name, shr = Store[code], Share(code)
    sopen = float( shr.get_open() )
    scurr = float( shr.get_price() )
    schange = scurr - sopen
    movement = 'down' if schange < 0 else 'up'
    print( format("{} is {} for the day. Current price is {}"), name, movement, scurr) )
    print( format('The price moved {} to the {}side today.',abs(schange), movement) )
    print('-----------------------')
```

Comment: Thank you so much @hjpotter92! And thanks for the link to code review.  I'll be sure to use that next time. :-)